# ASP.NET: inconsistent detection of Chrome browser

Tags: asp.net, browsercaps

I am testing an ASP.NET 3.5 app on 2 machines: one is a Windows 7 x64, and the other Windows Server 2008 x64.

When I use the same Chrome instance to open the websites on these 2 machines, I get different results on `HttpBrowserCapabilities.Browser`: on the Windows 7 machine I get `browser.Name = "appleMac-safari"`, while on the Windows Server machine I get `browser.Name = "applewebkit"`.

Both machine are have identical (AFAIK) installations of the asp.net app, same `machine.config` files, and the `*.browser` files are also identical on `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers`

Any ideas why this discrepancy happens?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to detect Chrome as it is more reliable

```
if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome"))
{
    ....
}
```

Where the UserAgent Value is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the user agent string the browser is sending in. Chances are, the user agent string is not the same in that version of chrome on those 2 platforms. There are lots of little differences.

Also, I would add that, in most cases, server-side browser sniffing has very limited uses because, as you have seen, it is not particularly reliable and can be easily faked. If you are looking to style things differently or tweak some client-side behavior, using a javascript package like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to do feature detection is a much more robust way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Will check Modernizr. But I am using the same browser instance (different tabs only) to access both sites, so it gotta be the same user agent, right?

Comment: Ahh, yes, it sure _should_ be the same user agent. I misunderstood your question as to where the app was and where the browser was. It still wouldn't hurt to compare the useragent string, as well as any other headers the browser is sending to see if there is a difference in any way.